# Excel (time format DD.MM.YY hh:mm) is not able to do proper time steps automatically

Tags: excel, time

I have come across this problem several times, so I would like to ask you now. I often need to create time series with hourly time steps (usually for the length of one year).

So I start to write

```
01.01.2001 00:00
01.01.2001 01:00
01.01.2001 02:00
```

Then I drag the the fill handle, so that Excel automatically fills the next lines until 31.12.2001. But, for what reason ever, there is a sudden jump of only 59 minutes instead of a full hour:

```
05.01.2001 03:00
05.01.2001 03:59
05.01.2001 04:59
```

Anybody else who came across this? And can me explain the reason and/or recommend alternatives for an automatic creation of the time series?

Comment: If your first date is in `A1`, do you get the same issue if you try `=A1+TIME(1,0,0)`, or `=A1+1/24`, in `A2` and drag down?

Comment: That's working fine. So I will use it as a workaround... thank you for your help!!! :-) (But still wondering why it's not working with my original attempt... Excel is weird!)

Answer (score 0):

In the first cell you need to change number format to

```
dd.mm.rrrr g:mm;@
```

Then you can write your first date and time. When you drag the fill to the second cell - edit it to get next hour. Then when you select this two cell and drag fill handle you'll get automatically time series +hour

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeJM6.png)

Comment: Do you know if there is an alternative for "rrrr" for the German version? I haven't found it on google. I am using the German version, so my original try was actually with TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm. Excel doesn't recnogize TT.MM.rrrr..... I also tried TT.MM.JJJJ g:mm;@ but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: So I think it should be: TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm;@

Comment: Unfortunately, TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm;@ does not work either. There is still that jump from 05.01.2001 03:00 to 05.01.2001 03:59. But, I am working now with the workaround suggested by @BigBen, so I am fine at the moment :-)